# Content Fields Group Wrapper without View- Drupal7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, field, overlay, content-type

I am newbie into Drupal. I am using Drupal-7.

I wanted to create fields group with wrapper. Somewhat like View Block. But, don't want to use View-Block. So, is there any way to create group for three content fields into content type, and give div wrapper to those group of fields?

For example:

Three fields are:

```
Heading
Text
Link
```

I wanted to create text overlay box for theses three fields. Text overlay box has fixed height and background color. So, I wanted create one div wrapper that has theses three fields(heading, text and link). I know textoverlay will be done with css like position: absolute; But need to give fixed height and background-color for textbox(not just for sing field).

If its html code then it will be like:

```
<div id="textoverlay_box" class="textoverlay_box">
     <div id="text_heading">
     </div>
     <div id="overlay_textarea">
     </div>
     <div id="overlay_textlink">
     </div>
</div>
```

In CSS,

```
#textoverlay_box {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100px;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.5;
 height: 62px;
 width: 253px;
}
```

But, not sure how to do it in Drupal-7 without using View.

Any advice?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!!!!

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Field Group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group). It allows you to group fields in the display settings of a node/entity.